# The correct format of application.properties in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am confused here: 
in the documentation on the [properties section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) there is an example on how to modify stuff in 
application.properties

```
spring.main.web_environment=false
spring.main.show_banner=false
```

Note that the above uses the  "=" sign to apply values to the properties

In the spring-boot documentation in the logging section there is an example on how to modify logg levels

```
ogging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
```

Note that the above uses the  ":" sign to apply values to the properties

- What is the correct way to set properties? If you test it both ways works!
- Is there a typo in the docs and the second example is actually for application.yaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the javadoc of `java.util.Properties`:

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line terminator.